# Not able to set the context for MediaPlayer.create

Tags: android, gmail

I want to eatract the mail id's of the person sending the mail in gmail via this code and play it out using the Media Player char by char. But in the try block when I declare MediaPlayer.create(MailSender.this,R.raw.sound), the create is underlined and it says that it does not match (Context,int) type.

Even getApplicationContext() is not working. What do I do?The code is here

```
package com.mycomp.android.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MailSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {
MediaPlayer mPlayer=null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
             EmailManager ob=new EmailManager("user","password","gmail.com","smtp.gmail.com","imap.gmail.com");


             try {
                Message result[]=ob.getMails();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                       Log.d("From", result[i].getFrom()[0] + "");
                       String s=result[i].getFrom()[0].toString();
                       String formed=s;
                       if(s.contains("<")&&s.contains(">"))
                       {
                           formed="";
                           int start=s.indexOf('<');
                           int end=s.indexOf('>');

                           for(int j=start+1;j<end;j++)
                           {
                                  formed=formed+s.charAt(j);
                           }
                       }
                       System.out.println("Baby          "+formed);
                    MediaPlayer mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(MailSender.this,R.raw.a);
```

mPlayer.start();

```
                        //Call sound=new Call(formed);


                        Log.d("Subject", result[i].getSubject() + "");
                        String content = null;
                        try {
                            content = result[i].getContent().toString();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("content", content + "");

                    }
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return 1;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

}
```

Comment: I do not see any MediaPlayer declaration. Also, where is your main activity?

Comment: @babatenor The MediaPlayer declaration , as I told already, fails inside the try block in the doinBackground function.

Comment: @babatenor You need not worry about the main activity. The code is working fine. It is just about the failure of the declaration of Media Player.create

Comment: @babatenor I have mentioned it now. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is pretty straightforward: `MailSender` is an `AsyncTask` and hence not a valid reference to `Context`. In other words: an `AsyncTask` does not implement `Context`. That's why `MailSender.this` won't work, nor calling `getApplicationContext()`, because an `AsyncTask` does not have such a method.

There are two easy solutions to your problem:

- Define `MailSender` as inner class in your `Activity` and call `MediaPlayer.create(...)` with a reference to the outer class (as in: `MyActivity.this`).
- Add a constructor tot your `MailSender` class that takes a reference to a `Context`, e.g. the `Activity` from which you launch the task. Then call `MediaPlayer.create(...)` with that `Context` reference.

Furthermore, I doubt you'll want to call `MediaPlayer.create(...)` from a non-UI thread, though I have to admit I didn't try it. In stead I would suggest you use the built-in method that prepares the player in the background, called [`prepareAsync()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29). More details can be found in [the documentation for the `MediaPlayer` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

---

**Edit:** By adding a constructor I meant adding something like this to your `MailSender` class:

```
// member variable
private Context mContext;

public MailSender(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

// create the MediaPlayer using the context reference:
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, ...);
```

With this addition, simply instantiate the MailSender as follows (assuming `this` will refer to your `Activity`):

```
MailSender sender = new MailSender(this);
sender.execute();
```

Comment: How do I create the constructor as mentioned by you in the 2nd part which takes a reference to a context?? say I am calling the MailSender class from a class New.java

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer for some pointers. It's pretty straightforward, so I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Proved to be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it because the MediaPlayer expects an URI and it's impossible to create an URI for an assets file. Try creating a MediaPlayer object and setting a data source to it using the MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor) method. You can get the FileDescriptor object using the AssetManager.openFd() method and then calling the AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor() method for the returned object.